# Istio - How to add custom label-based metrics?

Tags: prometheus, istio, envoyproxy

I am using istio 1.6.3

I would like to add a simple dimension to the metrics exported by istio to prometheus.
More specifically, if my Pod has a label `branch=master`, I'd like to add a
`branch` dimension with the `master` value to the `istio_requests_total` metric.

(I tried adding this label on the service level, without avail)

My goal is to then be able to query the metrics on prometheus, with

`sum(rate(istio_requests_total[5m])) by (branch)`

I read this piece of documentation: https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/metrics/customize-metrics/

But it seems like getting the `destination.labels["branch"]`, or getting any label at all is not supported (apart from the `app` or `version` labels, which are builtin `destination_app` and `destination_version`).

Help!

Comment: I'm using 1.6.3 as well and I do see my kube pods labels mapped as prometheus labels. I'm not 100% sure but I think this is enabled when you pass the "meshConfig.enablePrometheusMerge=true" option to istio install.

Comment: PS: this can be achieved without even playing with custom metrics. Just configure 'kubernetes-pods' job in prometheus configmap to enable labelmap, if not already there

Comment: As @Joel mentioned you could try to use  `meshConfig.enablePrometheusMerge=true` option. There is related [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/integrations/prometheus/#option-2-metrics-merging) about that. Just a notice that this option is newly introduced in Istio 1.6 and is considered alpha at this time.

Answer (score 1):

So just as a reference.

1. Istio configures prometheus with a 'kubernetes-pods' job. At least while using the 'demo' profile. In this prometheus job config, there is a

```
relabel_configs: 
...
- action: labelmap
  regex: __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_(.+)
```

Which gets the pod labels.

2. Enabling `meshConfig.enablePrometheusMerge=true` on the istio operator or whathever installation you are using will append the labels to the istio metrics.